# Problem building Rust executable and Docker image for Mac M1: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: linux, bash, docker, rust

```
# Use an official Rust runtime as a parent image
FROM rust:bookworm as builder

# Set the working directory in the image to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev openssl curl

# Set the environment variables
ENV DATABASE_URL postgres://postgres:secret@pg:5432/mydatabase
ENV REDIS_URL=redis://redis/
ENV S3_ENDPOINT=http://minio1:9000
ENV S3_ACCESS_KEY=minioadmin
ENV S3_SECRET_KEY=minioadmin
ENV S3_BUCKET_NAME=mybucket

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the wait script to the image
COPY ee/k8s/readiness-probe.sh /app/readiness-probe.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/readiness-probe.sh

COPY ./target/release/run_consumer /app/run_consumer
COPY ./target/release/assistants-api-communication /app/assistants-api-communication

# Copy the entrypoint script
COPY docker/entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh

# Make the entrypoint script executable
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh

# Run the entrypoint script when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Run the consumer and server applications concurrently
run_consumer &
assistants-api-communication &

# Wait for all background processes to finish
wait
```

Commands I run on a Mac M2:

```bash
cargo build --release --bin run_consumer
cargo build --release --bin assistants-api-communication

docker build -t foo:latest -f docker/Dockerfile .
    
docker run --env-file .env -p 8080:8080 foo:latest
```

The entrypoint.sh crashes with:

> cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

What I tried:

- add `--platform linux/arm64` or `linux/arm64/v8`
- inspecting the image architecture (arm64)
- copying the executable to host and do `file` on it (arm64)
- executing the executable on host - works
- trying different runtime images (rust:bookworm, ubuntu, etc.)
- using same build and runtime image
- running the docker image one of the with the executable in `--entrypoint` directly

Note: I don't build the exec in the image for a specific reason that I don't want to change yet.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem was that I was putting a `arm` executable in a non `arm` environment** (container), I also managed to build inside the Docker container by using

```bash
cargo sqlx prepare --workspace
```

Putting the `.sqlx` in the build and setting `ENV SQLX_OFFLINE true`

```
FROM rust:bookworm as builder

# Set the working directory in the image to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY assistants-api-communication /app/assistants-api-communication
COPY assistants-core /app/assistants-core
COPY assistants-extra /app/assistants-extra
COPY Cargo.toml /app/Cargo.toml
COPY .sqlx /app/.sqlx

ENV SQLX_OFFLINE true

RUN cargo build --release --bin run_consumer && \
    cargo build --release --bin assistants-api-communication

# Start a new stage to create a lean final image
FROM debian:bookworm-slim

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev openssl curl

# Set the environment variables
ENV DATABASE_URL postgres://postgres:secret@postgres:5432/mydatabase
ENV REDIS_URL=redis://redis/
ENV S3_ENDPOINT=http://minio1:9000
ENV S3_ACCESS_KEY=minioadmin
ENV S3_SECRET_KEY=minioadmin
ENV S3_BUCKET_NAME=mybucket

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the wait script to the image
COPY ./ee/k8s/readiness-probe.sh /app/readiness-probe.sh
RUN chmod +x /app/readiness-probe.sh

# Copy the binary from the builder stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/run_consumer /usr/local/bin/run_consumer
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/assistants-api-communication /usr/local/bin/assistants-api-communication

# Copy the entrypoint script
COPY ./docker/entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh

# Make the entrypoint script executable
RUN chmod +x /app/entrypoint.sh

# Run the entrypoint script when the container launches
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Thanks! It's open source: https://github.com/stellar-amenities/assistants

Comment: `arm` isn't the issue here, the container and the host machine run on the same hardware architecture. Like I said, the issue comes from the fact that you built your Rust application on your host machine which runs on **MacOS**, and ran the application on an Ubuntu container which is a **Linux Type OS**. So it's an OS issue, not a physical issue. Building the application in `rust:bookworm` and running it in a `debian:bookworm-slim` container works because both are Debian-Based and Docker will make sure to pull ARM platform images.

Answer (score 0):

Here you **build** your Rust application on your host machine which runs on **MacOS**, and **run** the application on an Ubuntu container which is a **Linux Type OS**. The difference between both OS architectures is likely why you're having this issue.

> I don't build the exec in the image for a specific reason that I don't
> want to change yet.

I see no reason why building your app in a Docker container is an issue. On the contrary, this is what you should do, otherwise you will be stuck with your issue.

Moreover your `builder` stage is actually useless in your case because no further stage depends on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to release image for ubuntu you need to build the binary which is consistent with its architecture as well. You can specify the target as linux and cross compile your code for ubuntu.

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
cargo build --release --bin run_consumer --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Do note that cross compilation has its own troubles it will not always work depending on what dependencies you are using but that's the best in your scenario since you want to build for ubuntu.